# GridView onItemClickListener NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, dialog, nullpointerexception

I'm working with a gridView which onItemClickListener opens a dialog box, but I get a NPE at the dialog box , and I can't figure out how to solve it. Thanks a lot !

Here is my Galerie.java:

```
package com.descoper.rom;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Galerie extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
     GalerieAdapter customGridAdapter;
     private Dialog dialog;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galerie);

        //set grid view item
        Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ro);
        Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ro);

        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"House"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Friend"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Personal"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Building"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"xyz"));


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        customGridAdapter = new GalerieAdapter(this, R.layout.galerie_row, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) customGridAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0){
                    dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
                    dialog.setTitle(position);

                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    Button btnSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }


               if(position == 1){
                   Toast.makeText(Galerie.this, "APASATAAAAAAA" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               if(position ==2){
                   Toast.makeText(Galerie.this, "APASATAAAAAAA" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**dialog1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**logcat:**

```
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): Process: com.descoper.rom, PID: 1272
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:156)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:133)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.descoper.rom.Galerie$1.onItemClick(Galerie.java:61)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-29 15:38:59.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Line 61 in Galerie.java:**

```
dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Activity` context to show the dialog , not the `getApplicationContext`.

Change

```
    dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
    dialog = new Dialog(Galerie.this);
```

When you use context in order to modify the UI, you should use the Activity context , because dialog is owned by Activity. ie Galerie.this

When you use context to do non-activity works, then you should use Application Context.

Comment: Working now.Thanks a lot. One more thing, can you explain me why is that? What's the difference between getAplicationContent() and Galerie.this? Thanks a lot !

Comment: agreed. One thing I find odd, though, is why does the constructor of `Dialog` takes a `Context`, and not just and `Activity`, since it will not work if the context is not an activity.

Comment: Agreed. But even the Activity entends  the Context class.  So it does'nt matter

Comment: If you use DialogFragment , it needs Fragment Manager associated with Activity , to show the dialog. That would have avoided this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the

```
dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
```

outside of the `onItemClick`.

And also, use **`dialog = new Dialog(this);`** instead of `dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext())`.

Comment: Not working. I worked with dialog boxes before, and this should be created onClick only, not onCreate of the activity. Thanks !